# C++ считывание массива чисел в вектор векторов

Tags: c++, vector, вектор

В текстовом файле представлены строки целых чисел. Числа в каждой строке разделены между собой знаком пробела.  Заранее неизвестно сколько в файле строк и неизвестно сколько в каждой строке чисел(их количество в каждой строке может быть различно). Вопрос: как считать данные из файла в вектор векторов?

Comment: Никаких соображений нет?

Comment: Открываете учебник, читаете как прочитать построчно текстовый файл, как разбить прочитанные строки на подстроки используя пробел, как подстроки конвертировать в числа. Попутно разбираетесь с контейнерами для хранения объектов. Не хотите читать учебник - гуглите биржу фриланса и там размещаете Ваш заказ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов, разбирайтесь:

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> data;
    ifstream in("data");
    string buf;
    while(getline(in,buf))
    {
        istringstream is(buf);
        vector<int> v;
        copy(istream_iterator<int>(is),istream_iterator<int>(),
             back_inserter(v));
        data.push_back(v);
    }


    for(auto row: data)
    {
        for(auto col: row)
            cout << setw(5) << col;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый Harry, бывают ситуации, когда ни преподаватель, ни студент не могут понять чужой код, который студент принес на сдачу лабы. Однако код работает, и тупой доцент ставит молча тупому студенту зачет, дабы у студента, в следствии тупых вопросов препа, не могла возникнуть мысль, что доцент еще тупее его. ИМХО, я бы не стал поощрять возможную халяву, даже в виде такого иезуитского ответа :).

Comment: Уважаемый Harry, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Уважаемый  Александр Муксимов, это вы зря. Мне теперь есть от чего отталкиваться

Comment: Да не за что... Если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ, как принятый.